# High CPU Utilisation Issue due to more Open connections of Oracle NOSql

Tags: node.js, npm, oracle-nosql

When running an NodeJs application with OracleNosql, found multiple connections are being open and not getting closed after execution. When there is a high throughput or request timeout issue case also the connections are opening large in count and not getting closed. Can anyone suggest how to control huge open connections between nodejs application and oraclenosql.

https://oracle.github.io/nosql-node-sdk/global.html#Config Here at this documentation too, could not find any max connection pool-size property configuration.

Edit1:

```
 public noSQLClient: NoSQLClient = new NoSQLClient({
        serviceType: ServiceType.KVSTORE,
        endpoint: env.DB_HOST
    });
```

Comment: Please take a look at httpOpt in Config.  You can specify the same options as used to construct HTTP.Agent in node.js.  Try to set maxFreeSockets option.  There are also maxSockets and maxTotalSockets, but those limit total number of sockets, not just unused.  Try maxFreeSockets, please let know if setting it helps.

Comment: @YevgeniyP I'm new to nodes js, can you please help me in how to create httpOpt and pass the reference in the config code. Added my config code in the question.

Comment: Ok, i posted an example.  It seems though the default value for maxFreeSockets is 256, so its not a huge number.  In your case, perhaps first try setting keepAlive to false, this should make sure that no connections are left open but may slow down the performance because new connection will have to be created for each request.

Comment: Another question, how many concurrent requests does your application issue?

Comment: On an average at minimum 100 users  found the issue, When we ran PT found 10000 open connections, which is greater than maxFreeSockets- 256, what would be the reason any idea

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what is PT? Can you post the output or the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add httpOpt as follows:

```
public noSQLClient: NoSQLClient = new NoSQLClient({
    serviceType: ServiceType.KVSTORE,
    endpoint: env.DB_HOST,
    httpOpt: {
       keepAlive: true,
       maxSockets: 128,
       maxFreeSockets: 64,
       .....
    }
});
```

The particular numbers above are just as example.

Another thing that you can do is to set keepAlive to false  (by default it is set to true currently):

```
public noSQLClient: NoSQLClient = new NoSQLClient({
    serviceType: ServiceType.KVSTORE,
    endpoint: env.DB_HOST,
    httpOpt: {
       keepAlive: false
    }
});
```

This will make sure that no free sockets are open, but may affect the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the configuration, will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your application shares a single `NoSQLClient` handle rather than creating more than one in the same process. And when you are done with it be sure to call its `close()` method to release resources.